# Convert JSON structure into Array : Groovy

Tags: arrays, json, groovy

I have below payload and I want to convert schedule elements into array with square brackets .

```
{
   "value":{
      "ID":"1c1238c8-3517-47c7-83de-6269fa6098cc",
      "scheduleElements":{
         "ID":"92a1352d-8319-4e1a-b921-0d7d0ee9f59e",
         "parentItem_ID":"1c1238c8-3517-47c7-83de-6269fa6098cc",
         "startDate":"2025-05-30",
      }
   }
}
```

I want to convert as below payload how do I do that ?

```
"value":{
      "ID":"1c1238c8-3517-47c7-83de-6269fa6098cc",
      "scheduleElements":**[**{
         "ID":"92a1352d-8319-4e1a-b921-0d7d0ee9f59e",
         "parentItem_ID":"1c1238c8-3517-47c7-83de-6269fa6098cc",
         "startDate":"2025-05-30",
      }**]**
   }
}
```

Comment: Please add the code you have tried and how it failed (e.g. errors,
stacktraces, logs, ...) so we can improve on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code:

```
import groovy.json.*

def data = '''
{
   "value":{
      "ID":"1c1238c8-3517-47c7-83de-6269fa6098cc",
      "scheduleElements":{
         "ID":"92a1352d-8319-4e1a-b921-0d7d0ee9f59e",
         "parentItem_ID":"1c1238c8-3517-47c7-83de-6269fa6098cc",
         "startDate":"2025-05-30",
      }
   }
}
'''

def json = new JsonSlurper().parseText(data)

json.value.scheduleElements = [json.value.scheduleElements]

def result = JsonOutput.prettyPrint(JsonOutput.toJson(json))

println result
```

when executed, prints:

```
─➤ groovy solution.groovy
{
    "value": {
        "ID": "1c1238c8-3517-47c7-83de-6269fa6098cc",
        "scheduleElements": [
            {
                "ID": "92a1352d-8319-4e1a-b921-0d7d0ee9f59e",
                "parentItem_ID": "1c1238c8-3517-47c7-83de-6269fa6098cc",
                "startDate": "2025-05-30"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```